# can i get var by its name string in python?

Tags: python

in this code

```
var01="0101001"
str01="var01"
```

are there any ways to call "0101001" by str01?
I want to get values by loop

if function '$' can make str to get val of var with that name

```
for i in range(0,33):

    $("var"+str(i).zfill(2))
```

```
>>>[0101001,.....
```

is there any function like '$'?

Comment: you can use a dict

Comment: Don't do this. Use a *container* like a list or a dict.